# Stackelberg solution to $n$-player Hotelling's game on a segment

Tags: gt.game-theory

Suppose that several agents need to place points (one per
agent) on the interval $[0,1]$. An agent's goal is to maximize the
volume of the Voronoi cell that contains his point. When $n$ agents must
place their points sequentially, is an optimal strategy known?

From what I was able to glean from the literature so far, it appears I am asking for the Stackelberg solution to an $n$-player Hotelling's game on a segment.

Comment: I am not asking people to solve this question for me, just wondering what is known about it -- and the obvious extension to 2 dimensions.

Comment: I think these are usually called *Voronoi games*. I don't know much about them, but I think by searching that keyword you can find out what is known.

Comment: Thanks! I was only able to find references for 2-player Voronoi games.

Comment: There may only be research for the 2-player case (don't know)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This game has been studied in

> Hee-Kap Ahn, Siu-Wing Cheng, Otfried Cheong, Mordecai Golin, René van Oostrum:
>   "Competitive facility location: the Voronoi game"
>   Theoretical Computer Science 310, 2004, pp 457-467

There also are lots of follow-up works, as for instance

> Sayan Bandyapadhyay, Aritra Banik, Sandip Das, Hirak Sarkar:
>   "Voronoi game on graphs"
>   Theoretical Computer Science 562, 2015, pp 270-282

Comment: Still wondering -- has it been studied for $> 2$ players?